# Checking what methods were invoked during execution typescript on node js server (debugging nodejs)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am developer with poor experience, however with strong academic CS background. 
So please be patient where I am wrong somewhere.

As far I know, typescript can be executed on JS server and it works in this way in my case. Namely, I execute e2e tests with protactor (angular test framework).

I would like to debug it and check what methods was called during such execution on nodejs. To give you more details, I would like if (and possibly parameters) was invoked 
`waitForAngular(rootSelector, callback)` method.

I know that it is possible to dump a variety of traces and debugging info from JVM, however I have no idea how can I do it with nodejs in my specific case.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Around where you have your calls to `waitForAngular` (or any other code that you want to check), add a `console.trace()`, which will display a stack trace at that exact line of code.

You can read more about console.trace() and other console API methods at this document by the Chrome project (node.js uses the JS engine that Chrome uses): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/api#trace

Answer (score 0):

You can sprinkle `debugger` statements in your code to stop execution which will allow you to step through your code.  Similarly, you could start your Node process with the [`--inspect-brk`](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js) argument to use Chrome DevTools to step through your code.